# How do I change a button on hover?

Tags: html, css

I need help to create a image change when hovered over.  I am using this image as a button.  This is my code:

```
.button_home {
    width: 110px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(background1.png);
}
.button_home :hover {
    background-image: url(background_ov1.png);
}
```

my html is:

```
<form action="webpage.HTML">
<input type="image" class="button_home">
</form>
```

Any help please?

Comment: Take out the space between `.button_home` and `:hover`

Comment: Change `.button_home :hover` to `.button_home:hover`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the space before `:hover`

```
.button_home:hover {
```